# lightning-input type date time picks incorrect time value

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I'm using `lightning-input type="datetime"` to take datetime input from a user inside a lightning web component. I initially bind the value returned from back-end to the input. It displays the correct date-time value fetched from back-end on the date-time picket.

However, when I call a js method on change of input, it fetches incorrect value.

So, in my case I'm displaying 12:00 PM to the user initially (fetched from back-end sfdc record). Now, if user updates the value to 12:15 PM, the handler updates the value on change. I use console to see the updated value and it displays 19:15 instead of 12:15 PM.. any idea why?

Below is the code snippet:

```html
    <lightning-input type="datetime"
                                    label="Last Date"
                                    value={endDate}
                                    onchange={captureDateTimeChange}>
                    </lightning-input>
```

JS:

```js
captureDateTimeChange(event){
    console.log('DateTime : ' ,event.target.value);
}
```

**Selected DateTime from datetime picker**

[image]

**Captured Date in js method:**

[image]

What's causing the js method to pick incorrect date ?

Answer (score 1):

It is converting to UTC time. Whatever shown to you is depends on user's locale.
E.g. Users locale is set to GMT +5:00, he'll see 5:00 PM, where as time is stored as 12:00PM.

Please find the text from [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/documentation) -

> A datetime field includes a text input to type a date and a date
> picker to select a date, and similar fields for typing or picking a
> time. Your Salesforce locale setting determines the acceptable date
> and time formats. Your Salesforce language setting determines the
> names of months and weekdays that the date picker displays.
>
> The date and time you enter are automatically validated against your
> Salesforce locale format during the blur event. The date and time
> displayed reflect your Salesforce time zone setting. Use the timezone
> attribute to specify a different time zone in IANA time zone database
> format. For example, specify timezone="America/New_York" for US
> Eastern Time or timezone="GMT" for Greenwich Mean Time.

Comment: in that case, shouldn't it display the date/time in datetime picker as per the locale? Why is there a discrepancy in what's displayed inside datetime picker and what is actually shown in console?

Comment: No, on UI it'll show the locale but when you save it, it'll saved as UTC.

Comment: So, that'd lead to Erroneous data being stored in the back-end. Is there a way I can convert it back to system time zone?

Comment: @sfdcnoob If you're using the appropriate date/datetime methods, the data saved should be correct. We'd have to see more code related to your problem to help you. Please read about the [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Hi @sfdcnoob because of the terrible design of the lightning-input defaulting to the salesforce timezone (seriously, who came up with that?) you can set the `timezone` attribute to `new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-us', { timeZoneName: 'short' }).split(' ')[2];` to get the abbreviated time